# To consume a web service using Symfony2

Tags: php, web-services, symfony

[symfony]
Hello everyone,

Here's my problem,

In fact I would like to know how to consume a web service using Symfony2.

I have at my disposal the address of the web service to consume and methods that go with it!

I create the bundle to send requests to the server or is the web service. The thing is I sis not how to send the request.

Link my webservice:
http://www.localhost:81/drupal/spid/
  If anyone has a method to use this webservice in Symfony2.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no built in way to execute HTTP requests in Symfony.  There are several ways to do this inside of Symfony using other PHP functions.  cUrl is a good place to start.  you can do something like this to make a GET request

```
$curl_request = curl_init("http://localhost:81/drupal/spid/");
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($curl_request); // execute the request
curl_close($curl_request);
```

for more info on curl, check the [PHP docs](https://php.net/curl)

Comment: Hi I try. It gives me com response: The requested URL / drupal / spid / spid / user / login was not found on this server.

Comment: then the url does not exist that you are requesting. If I understand correctly, your API is on the same server as your Symfony app?  Is that how you have it setup?

Answer (score 1):

We use the Guzzle bundle for our web service requests. It's a http client for Symfony2, which uses cURL. You can find it @ https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle